# Unable to setup MongoDB 3.6 Cluster Setup on Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, authentication, replicaset

I am building the MongoDB 3 node cluster in Linux environment. But I am not able to run my authentication enabled mode. Please help me to understand what is the point I am missing. I have listed all the steps which I have followed,

1)All the 3 nodes are having the below configuration file.

```html
# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /storage/mongodb/data/db
  directoryPerDB: true
  journal:
    enabled: true
  engine: wiredTiger
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /storage/mongodb/log/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017  
  bindIpAll: true  
  #ssl:
   
# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:      

#operationProfiling:

replication:
  oplogSizeMB: 10240
  replSetName: rs2

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

2) Below is the configuration of /etc/hosts in each machine

Server1:

```html
127.0.0.1 Server1
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Server2:

```html
127.0.0.1 Server2
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Server3:

```html
127.0.0.1 Server3
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

3)After all the configuration I have started the mongod service and connectedto the mongo client in Server1.

```html
MongoDB shell version v3.6.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.6.2
Server has startup warnings:
2018-03-05T19:36:50.717+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-03-05T19:36:50.717+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-03-05T19:36:50.717+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-03-05T19:36:50.717+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-03-05T19:36:50.717+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-03-05T19:36:50.717+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2018-03-05T19:36:50.717+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2018-03-05T19:36:50.717+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
> rs.status()
{
        "info" : "run rs.initiate(...) if not yet done for the set",
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "no replset config has been received",
        "code" : 94,
        "codeName" : "NotYetInitialized"
}
>
```

```html
> rs.initiate()
{
        "info2" : "no configuration specified. Using a default configuration for the set",
        "me" : "Server1:27017",
        "ok" : 1,
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1520278787, 1),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1520278787, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
}
rs2:OTHER>
```

```html
rs2:OTHER> rs.status()
{
        "set" : "rs2",
        "date" : ISODate("2018-03-05T19:40:24.836Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "term" : NumberLong(1),
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "optimes" : {
                "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1520278819, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1520278819, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "appliedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1520278819, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "durableOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1520278819, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(1)
                }
        },
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "Server1:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 214,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1520278819, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(1)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-03-05T19:40:19Z"),
                        "infoMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1520278788, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2018-03-05T19:39:48Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 1,
                        "self" : true
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1,
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1520278819, 1),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1520278819, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
}
rs2:PRIMARY>
```

4)After primary became active, I have executed the below steps to rename my 'server1' name with my priviate ip "10.0.1.136"

```html
rs2:PRIMARY> cfg = rs.conf()
{
        "_id" : "rs2",
        "version" : 1,
        "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "Server1:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                }
        ],
        "settings" : {
                "chainingAllowed" : true,
                "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
                "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
                "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
                "catchUpTimeoutMillis" : -1,
                "catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis" : 30000,
                "getLastErrorModes" : {

                },
                "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
                        "w" : 1,
                        "wtimeout" : 0
                },
                "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("5a9d9d0350e5eb7ba0b9a68b")
        }
}
rs2:PRIMARY> cfg.members[0].host = "10.0.1.136:27017"
10.0.1.136:27017
rs2:PRIMARY> rs.reconfig(cfg)
{
        "ok" : 1,
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1520279033, 1),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1520279033, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
}
rs2:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
        "set" : "rs2",
        "date" : ISODate("2018-03-05T19:43:56.027Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "term" : NumberLong(1),
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "optimes" : {
                "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1520279033, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1520279033, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "appliedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1520279033, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "durableOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1520279033, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(1)
                }
        },
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "10.0.1.136:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 426,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1520279033, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(1)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-03-05T19:43:53Z"),
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1520278788, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2018-03-05T19:39:48Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 2,
                        "self" : true
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1,
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1520279033, 1),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1520279033, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
}
rs2:PRIMARY>
```

5) After that I have created admin user in the Server1 .

```html
rs2:PRIMARY> use admin;
switched to db admin
> db.createUser({user: "mongoDBAdmin", pwd: "password", roles:[{role: "root", db: "admin"}]})
2018-03-05T19:48:53.685+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) failed
2018-03-05T19:48:53.686+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) ok
Successfully added user: {
        "user" : "mongoDBAdmin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "root",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ]
}
> show users;
{
        "_id" : "admin.mongoDBAdmin",
        "user" : "mongoDBAdmin",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "root",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ]
}
>
```

6) Then I have connected to the Server2 mongo client and verified the rs.status() . Its not yet initiated.

```html
MongoDB shell version v3.6.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.6.2
Server has startup warnings:
2018-03-05T19:46:17.000+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-03-05T19:46:17.000+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-03-05T19:46:17.000+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-03-05T19:46:17.000+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-03-05T19:46:17.000+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-03-05T19:46:17.000+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2018-03-05T19:46:17.000+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2018-03-05T19:46:17.000+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
> rs.status()
{
        "info" : "run rs.initiate(...) if not yet done for the set",
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "no replset config has been received",
        "code" : 94,
        "codeName" : "NotYetInitialized"
}
```

7) Server2 is ready to join with the Server1. My private ip of Server2 is "10.0.1.137". So I have ran the following command in Server1(10.0.1.136).

```html
> rs.add("10.0.1.137:27017")
{
        "ok" : 1,
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1520279899, 1),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1520279899, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
}
> rs.status()
{
        "set" : "rs2",
        "date" : ISODate("2018-03-05T19:58:22.470Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "term" : NumberLong(3),
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "optimes" : {
                "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1520279899, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(3)
                },
                "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1520279899, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(3)
                },
                "appliedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1520279899, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(3)
                },
                "durableOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1520279899, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(3)
                }
        },
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "10.0.1.136:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 1292,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1520279899, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(3)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-03-05T19:58:19Z"),
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1520279205, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2018-03-05T19:46:45Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 3,
                        "self" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "10.0.1.137:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 3,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1520279899, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(3)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1520279899, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(3)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-03-05T19:58:19Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2018-03-05T19:58:19Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-03-05T19:58:21.031Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-03-05T19:58:19.454Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "configVersion" : 3
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1,
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1520279899, 1),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1520279899, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
}
>
```

8) Now both primary and secondary are in sync. So I am able to see the admin user in the secondary node as well.

```html
rs2:SECONDARY> show users;
2018-03-05T20:00:40.457+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: not master and slaveOk=false :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.getUsers@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1686:1
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:796:9
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:703:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1
rs2:SECONDARY> rs.slaveOk()
rs2:SECONDARY> use admin;
switched to db admin
rs2:SECONDARY> show users;
{
        "_id" : "admin.mongoDBAdmin",
        "user" : "mongoDBAdmin",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "root",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ]
}
rs2:SECONDARY>
```

9) For the testing purpose I have not connected with 'Server3'. Now I am going to enable the authentication with the keyfile. So /etc/mongod.conf needs to be modified.Below is the updated conf file in the both servers.

Already I have generated keyfile and copied to both servers . Assigned the required permissions as well.

Updated configuration file.

```html
# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /storage/mongodb/data/db
  directoryPerDB: true
  journal:
    enabled: true
  engine: wiredTiger
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true  
  path: /storage/mongodb/log/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017  
  bindIpAll: true  
  #ssl:   
# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

security:
  authorization: enabled  
  keyFile: /etc/mongodb/ssl/keyfile

#operationProfiling:

replication:
  oplogSizeMB: 10240
  replSetName: rs2

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

10) After configuration modification I have restarted the mongod service in the primary(Server1). But client is not connecting.

I have tried different way,

```html
User1@Server1:/storage/mongodb/data/db$ sudo service mongod restart
User1@Server1:/storage/mongodb/data/db$
User1@Server1:/storage/mongodb/data/db$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.6.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-03-05T20:11:47.746+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-03-05T20:11:47.746+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
User1@Server1:/storage/mongodb/data/db$ mongo --host 10.0.1.136 --port 27017
MongoDB shell version v3.6.2
connecting to: mongodb://10.0.1.136:27017/
2018-03-05T20:12:06.069+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 10.0.1.136:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-03-05T20:12:06.070+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 10.0.1.136:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
User1@Server1:/storage/mongodb/data/db$ mongo --host Server1 --port 27017
MongoDB shell version v3.6.2
connecting to: mongodb://Server1:27017/
2018-03-05T20:12:21.237+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-03-05T20:12:21.237+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server Prod-App04:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
User1@Server1:/storage/mongodb/data/db$ mongo --host Server1 --port 27017 -u "mongoDBAdmin" -p "password"
MongoDB shell version v3.6.2
connecting to: mongodb://Server1:27017/
2018-03-05T20:12:57.149+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-03-05T20:12:57.149+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server Prod-App04:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I don't know really what I am missing. Even I am not able to connect to single machine using the mongo client. Please help me what I want to do as a next step ?

Comment: It's strongly recommended to not create a replica set configuration using IP addresses. This would be problematic if your IP changes, and could lead to the confusion you experienced. To setup a replica set using keyfile, please follow the procedure in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-with-keyfile-access-control/#deploy-repl-set-with-auth

Comment: The first place to look is in the mongo server log; your configuration specifies this as located in _/storage/mongodb/log/mongod.log_